# Isabelle: understanding the use of quantifiers

Tags: isabelle

I have found that I can prove the following lemma, which seems false to me.

```
lemma assumes "∀a b. f a > f b ∧ a ≠ b"
shows "∀a b. f b > f a"
using assms by auto
```

How can the lemma above be true? Is Isabelle substituting values as I have used the ∀ quantifier? If so, I want to state the for all values of a and b, f(a) is greater than f(b), how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does it seem false? You are stating that for ANY a and b, `f a > f b` and `a ≠ b`. This means that if say `a = 0` and `b = 1` then `f 0 > f 1` but also when `a = 1` and `b = 0` it means that `f 1 > f 0`.

Furthermore, you assume `∀a b. f a > f b ∧ a ≠ b` is true, this means you ASSUME that for any a and b, `f a > f b` AND a different from b. This is generally false as you can not have `∀a b. a ≠ b`

Maybe what you meant to say was: `∀a b. (a ≠ b ==> f a > f b)`? eg. for any a and b, if `a ≠ b` then `f a > f b`? Note that this still implies `f b > f a` as per the example above, it it really isn't saying anything meaningful.

Comment: I understand, I was confused. How would I represent for a in the set S, f a is greater than f b, where b also belongs to the set S?

Comment: Instead of `∀a b. a ≠ b ==> f a > f b` (which is parsed as `(∀a b. a ≠ b) ==> f a > f b`) you probably want `∀a b. a ≠ b --> f a > f b`.

Comment: Note that this is probably not what you want, because that would mean that for any `a` and `b` with `a ≠ b`, you have both `f a < f b` and `f a > f b`. This should not hold for any sensible ordering.

Comment: @creator22, can you give a concrete example of such a set S?
I'm asking because if I understand your question right, you seem to be saying: if `S = {1,2}` then `f 1 > f 2`, but also `f 2 > f 1`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The lemma you state is trivially true. Almost a direct instance of "A ==> A". From your assumption it may trivially be concluded that `∀a b. f a > f b`. Then by renaming bound variables appropriately we obtain `∀b a. f b > f a`. Moreover all-quantifiers may be reordered to obtain `∀a b. f b > f a`.